# Python + STOMP not receiving messages from ActiveMQ

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I recently had a task to make Python script which can read/receive and show message from ActiveMQ. It has the methods `on_message` and `on_error` which print "received message..." and "received error..." respectively. Unfortunately neither prints anything even though it has connection to ActiveMQ.
[image: As you can see I created topic in web console named "topictest"]

```
import time
import sys
import stomp

class ConnectionListener(object):
    def on_error(self, message):
        print('received an error %s' % message)
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('received a message %s' % message)
        print(message.body)
        with open('/usr/ubuntu/result.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
            txt_file.write(str(message))
conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[('localhost', 61613)])
conn.set_listener('', ConnectionListener())


conn.connect("admin", "admin", wait=True)

conn.subscribe(destination='/topic/topictest', id='1', ack='auto')

time.sleep(2)
conn.disconnect()
```

Maybe the problem is on destination I gave. So I tried to change `destination='/topic/...'`. Nothing happens. I need my code to show the message.

Comment: Where there messages being actively sent to the topic in question while the client was connected?

Comment: I sent message manually to the topic in web console using "Sent to" button.@TimBish

Comment: You didn't answer my question, was the client connected to ActiveMQ when you sent the messages?  Topics do not retain messages and the client timeout looks to be 2 seconds so it seems unlikely

Comment: Yes, client  was connected. Otherwise, it would instantly show an error.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed the:

`conn.start()`

line before `conn.connect()` method.